# How to change styles for components while we reusing in react?

Tags: reactjs

I am working on react project, In that I have a parent component that is App.js. for that that App.js, Child.js is child component. In that Child.js  I put one icon and apply styles.

Now I want to reuse that Child.js component with a different background color, different icon, different border color.

How to achieve this is in react

This is App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Child from './Child/Child'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Child></Child>
      <Child></Child>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is Child.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './Child.css';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faCoffee } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

function Child() {
    return (
        <div className='container'>
            <div className='row'>
                <div className='col-12'>
                    <div class="exp">
                        <FontAwesomeIcon className='coffee' icon={faCoffee} />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Child
```

This is Child.css

```
.exp{
    width:80px;
    height:80px;
    background-color:red;
    border-radius:100%;
    line-height:80px;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    display:inline-block;
    border: solid 3px blue;
}

.coffee {
    color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple classes in your css file and then pass in the prop of the class name and icon you want to use in the component.

```
<Child iconClass="coffee" icon={faCoffee}/>

function Child(props) {
    return (
        <div className='container'>
            <div className='row'>
                <div className='col-12'>
                    <div class="exp">
                        <FontAwesomeIcon className={props.iconClass} icon={props.icon} />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the child to accept props and pass props when you render the component.

```
function Child({ icon, className}) {
  return (
    <div className='container'>
        <div className='row'>
            <div className='col-12'>
                <div class="exp">
                    <FontAwesomeIcon className={className} icon={icon} />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Child
```

Then use it like

```
<Child icon="faCoffee" className="style" />
<Child icon="faBars" className="style" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an `icon` props to render a JSX element in your Child component.

```
function Child({ icon }) {
    return (
        <div className='container'>
            <div className='row'>
                <div className='col-12'>
                    <div class="exp">
                        {icon}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

You can then write your Children component like this in your Parent component.

```
<Child icon={(<FontAwesomeIcon className='coffee' icon={faCoffee} />)} />
```